# What is an autoregressive decoder?

Tags: machine-learning, autoregressive

I saw that this was part of a deep belief network I was looking at.

I'm not sure what it means.

Is it a layer that transforms few inputs into many outputs and has a connection to itself?

What is an example of it?

Comment: I think it would be nice if you could add the paper that you were looking at, so we are able to give an answer with more context.

Answer (score 6):

I think the confusion stems from the term *autoregression*.

Autoregressive is anything that uses previous information from time steps to predict (regress) the output at the current time step. Refer to the links given below for more information on autoregression [1,2].
Examples can be any time series models, for example, predicting share prices based on historical share prices.

An autoregressive decoder is a decoder model which uses information from previous time steps of the decoder to generate the value at the current time step. An example of such an autoregressive decoder is a English-French machine translation model. While translating from English to French, the decoder will condition its current time step's prediction on the previously generated words (past time steps) [3].

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model
2. https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/autoregressive.asp
3. https://ojs.aaai.org/index.php/AAAI/article/download/4476/4354 (Wang, Yiren, et al. "Non-autoregressive machine translation with auxiliary regularization." Proceedings of the AAAI Conference on Artificial Intelligence. Vol. 33. No. 01. 2019.)

Comment: But does this answer the question? Can you explain autoregressive *decoder*?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I have edited the response to try to answer the question more specifically from the POV of an autoregressive decoder.

Answer (score 2):

decoder is a part that usually produces output from some hidden state. Autoregressive means that this is a recurrent structure that uses prediction from a previous state to generate next step, e.g. use previous predicted output word to generate next output word during translation.

Comment: Please cite references.